# unable to install python 3.6 on linux

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I run below commands after unzipping that python 3.6 tar.xz file.

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Error log:

```
ranlib libpython3.6m.a
gcc -pthread   -Xlinker -export-dynamic -o python Programs/python.o libpython3.6m.a -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lrt   -lm  
if test "no-framework" = "no-framework" ; then \
        /usr/bin/install -c python /usr/local/bin/python3.6m; \
    else \
        /usr/bin/install -c -s Mac/pythonw /usr/local/bin/python3.6m; \
    fi
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/bin/python3.6m': Read-only file system
make: *** [altbininstall] Error 1
```

When i run ./configure followed by make , and then make install i run into this error!

Comment: `sudo make install`

Comment: i'm already running as root user!

Comment: @KlausD. [root@machinename Python-3.6.1]# sudo make install
if test "no-framework" = "no-framework" ; then \
  /usr/bin/install -c python /usr/local/bin/python3.6m; \
 else \
  /usr/bin/install -c -s Mac/pythonw /usr/local/bin/python3.6m; \
 fi
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/bin/python3.6m': Read-only file system
make: *** [altbininstall] Error 1

Comment: Your file system is read only.

Comment: @KlausD Can't i do anything to make it work? I know the root password!

Comment: Fix the file system issue, which is not a programming topic and does not belong on SO. Or just use the non-installed version of Python.

Comment: @KlausD. Yeah i agree that this is not a programming issue, but a lot could benefit from my query! i changed the permission but still it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the above commands using `sudo` powers?

original answer: https://askubuntu.com/q/865554/667903

`sudo make install`

**or**

If you are using Ubuntu 16.10 or 17.04, then Python 3.6 is in the universe repository, so you can just run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

Comment: Yes i have done that. [root@slc05kyt Python-3.6.1]# sudo make install
if test "no-framework" = "no-framework" ; then \
  /usr/bin/install -c python /usr/local/bin/python3.6m; \
 else \
  /usr/bin/install -c -s Mac/pythonw /usr/local/bin/python3.6m; \
 fi
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/bin/python3.6m': Read-only file system
make: *** [altbininstall] Error 1

Comment: the machine uses yum

Answer (score 1):

Your filesystem seems to be read-only. You have to remount the partition where `/usr/local/bin/` is located with write permissions

The syntax for `mount` is

```
mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point
```

Let's say you have `/` on `/dev/sda2`

```
mount -o remount,rw / /dev/sda2
```

should fix your problem.

To check your mount points:
`cat /etc/fstab` or `df`

To check the permissions:
`cat /proc/mounts`

Comment: Thanks , i guess you identified the issue, i will try your solution and let you know how it went.

Answer (score 0):

Try after installing build essentials whic contains compilers,package dev tools and libs:
sudo apt-get install build-essential

Comment: My machine uses yum!